# App crashes - App receives low memory warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

In my app, I am getting low memory warning and app crashes after taking photos more than 100 from iPad camera. I used some memory management tools like instruments leaks- allocations, instrument doesn't show me any leak. But when I used allocation it shows me malloc 16bytes uses more allocation each time I opened camera view and takes photo, open my custom view.

I done google and I found code snippet to find out how much memory app uses

```
 -(void) report_memory {
struct task_basic_info info;
mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                               TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                               (task_info_t)&info,
                               &size);
if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
    NSLog(@"Memory in use (in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
  }
  }
```

Above code snippet also gives me same result as of instrument that app uses more allocation when i open camera and custom VC.

In my code I have used one category for creating thumbnail image using functions CGContextRef, CGColorSpaceRef, CGImageRef, imageWithCGImage etc. Is it making issue for crash?

Is there any other ways to find out or trace out reason for app crashing/ received memory warning? Or is there any other better ways in instruments to find out this?

Thanks..

Comment: You can get answers only by using Allocation Instruments. In that check what objects are utilizing memory on every snapshot of camera, those are not releasing from your application. Check the stack trace also

Comment: Have a look at the "iOS App Performance: Memory" session from this year's WWDC videos. It explains some possible reasons for the crash and how to fix them.

Comment: I checked instrument is not showing any leak...

Comment: The problem you are having is where all device memory is used up because you hold on to too many images in memory. Using leaks tools and checking memory usage is not usually going to show you where the problem is. The problem is in your code, but you need to fix it by thinking through your resource usage and checking for places where a ref to a UIImage, CGImageRef, or a ref to any view that holds a ref to one of these is held. Most of the time this is caused by improper holding on to UIView derived classes in a view controller. This is not easy, but auditing you code is the only way.